# Homology of wedge sum is the direct sum of homologies

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

I want to prove that $H_n(\bigvee_\alpha X_\alpha)\approx\bigoplus_\alpha H_n(X_\alpha)$ for good pairs (Hatcher defines a good pair as a pair $(X,A)$ such that $A\subset X$ and there is a neighborhood of $A$ that deformation retracts onto $A$).

**What I tried:**

Since $(X_\alpha, x_\alpha)$'s are good pairs, $(\bigsqcup X_\alpha, \{x_\alpha:\alpha\in I\})$ is a good pair, so a theorem (a long exact sequence argument) gives us an isomorphism $$q_*:H_n(\bigsqcup X_\alpha, \{x_\alpha:\alpha\in I\})\to H_n(\bigsqcup X_\alpha/\{x_\alpha:\alpha\in I\},\{x_\alpha:\alpha\in I\}/\{x_\alpha:\alpha\in I\})=H_n(\bigvee X_\alpha, \text{some point})$$ induced by the quotient map $$q:\bigsqcup X_\alpha, \{x_\alpha:\alpha\in I\})\to \bigsqcup X_\alpha/\{x_\alpha:\alpha\in I\},\{x_\alpha:\alpha\in I\}/\{x_\alpha:\alpha\in I\})=(\bigvee X_\alpha, \text{some point})$$

**Questions:**

Now, do these mean that we have an isomorphism $\phi:H_n(\bigsqcup X_\alpha)=\bigoplus H_n(X_\alpha) \to H_n(\bigvee X_\alpha)$? In general if we have an isomorphism $\theta:H_n(X,Y)\to H_n(A,B)$, then do we also have an isomorphism $\theta':H_n(X)\to H_n(A)$?

Comment: Look at the long exact sequences of the pairs $(X_\alpha, x_\alpha)$. What do they tell you. *Hint:* The theorem is actually wrong for $n=0$.

Comment: I think you mean reduced homology groups $\tilde H_n$

Comment: And regarding your last question: Surely not, any map $X\to A$ induces an isomorphism $H_n(X, X)\to H_(A, A)$.

Comment: @StefanH Actually, yes but they are the same for $n>0$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your proof is almost complete, let me suggest you some additional hint to complete it:

- there's an isomorphism 
  $$\tilde H_n(X) \cong H_n(X,x_0)$$
  between the reduced homology of a space $X$ and the homology of the pair $(X,x_0)$ where $x_0 \in X$;
- in the category of pairs of topological spaces there's an isomorphism
  $$H_n\left(\bigsqcup_\alpha (A_\alpha,B_\alpha)\right) \cong \bigoplus_\alpha H_n(A_\alpha, B_\alpha)$$
  for a family of pairs $(A_\alpha,B_\alpha)_\alpha$.

Combining these results with what you used should bring you to the solution of the problem.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Of course! I would like to write a complete solution but it took me a while to write this stuff in latex and I have little time but thank you very much

Comment: @Fanni you're welcome

Comment: Where can I find a proof of the second $\bullet$ ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ReinaldoR. it's a trivial result I believe you can find in every text book on algebraic topology. For instance in Hatcher's _Algebraic topology_ is (a consequence) of proposition 2.6 and the _short exact sequence lemma_.