# Creating a topological space a $1$ and a $2$-dimensional holes w.r.t homology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

I am trying to figure out how to create a topogical space with homology modules 
$$H_0X\cong H_1X \cong H_2X\cong \mathbb{Z}.$$

Intuitively, $H_0$is the number of path connected components, so this shouldn't be a problem. Similarly, using geometric intuition, one realizes that $H_i$ are roughly speaking the number of $i$-dimensional holes, and thus is led to the conclusion that "glueing" together the spaces $S^{2}$ and $S^1$, $X=S_1\cup_\alpha S_2$.

I am however left here with tho problems:

- How do I give explicitly the map $\alpha$ along which I attach $S^2, S^1$?
- How do I compute the Homology modules of the attached space? I only have access to a Theorem giving me an exact sequence for attaching $n-$discs, I don't know how to "transform" this to the case of $n$-spheres, which is the case I am in.

I would appreciate any help, hints or references to solutions.

Kindly
afightingchance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just take [the wedge sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedge_sum) $S^2\vee S^1$ (as the simpliest version of glueing) since

$$H_*(X\vee Y)\simeq H_*(X)\oplus H_*(Y)$$

for $*>0$. For the proof [look here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/519161/homology-of-wedge-sum-is-the-direct-sum-of-homologies).

Since $S^2\vee S^1$ is connected then $H_0(S^2\vee S^1)\simeq\mathbb{Z}$ and you're done.

Comment: You want reduced homology.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Fair enough, updated the answer.

Comment: @freakish how can I see that the wedge sum of $S_1$ and $S_2$ is connected?

Comment: @user502427 wedge sum of path connected spaces is path connected since for any point theres a path connecting it to the point of glueing.