# Removing Homology Groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I was trying to construct a space that has first $n$ homology groups any given abelian groups $G_1, ..., G_n$. To show this I would like to be able to do the following: Given any space $X$, I can form some $X'$ such that $H_j(X') = 0$ some fixed $j$ and $H_i (X) = H_i (X')$ for all $i \not = j$, i.e. a process of 'filling in $j$-dimensional holes'.

I do not see a way to proceed. It seems plausible but perhaps as I can only draw 'nice' spaces in my head.

Does any such process exist?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by taking a [wedge product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/519161/homology-of-wedge-sum-is-the-direct-sum-of-homologies) of [Moore spaces.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_space_(algebraic_topology)) Your question can then be answered by reading how Moore spaces are constructed. See Hatcher's book, Example 2.40 and Example 2.41 (2015 print).

Comment: I see that this allows us to solve my original question, but out of interest is it still possible to remove homology groups in general?

Comment: @Isomorphism The ideas used to construct Moore spaces work equally well to achieve your goals, but at the moment I'd have to go through them in a bit more detail to give you a more instructive answer. Now, I can tell you that the main tool to use is the cellular complex of your space (which you can assume is a CW-complex). Adding cells with appropriate characteristic maps will change the differential accordingly to kill the cycles you want.