# The n-sphere is not a deformation retract of the bouquet of k n-spheres

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, spheres, exterior-algebra, higher-homotopy-groups

I'm trying to show that $S^n$ is not a deformation retract of $\bigvee^k S^n$ as a generalization of a proof (or an attempt) I made showing that $S^1$ is not a deformation retract of $S^1\vee S^1$, but for all $n$ and all $k$ I couldn't prove that.

In the case when $k=2$ and $n=1$, if $S^1$ was a deformation retract of $S^1\vee S^1$, then  $S^1$ should be homotopy equivalent to $S^1\vee S^1$; moreover, if $S^1$ was homotopy equivalent to $S^1 \vee S^1$, its fundamental groups should be isomorphic. But $\pi_1(S^1)\cong \mathbb{Z}$ and $\pi_1(S^1\vee S^1)\cong \pi_1(S^1)\ast \pi_1(S^1)\cong \mathbb{Z}\ast \mathbb{Z}$, which are not isomorphic, then $S^1$ cannot be homotopy equivalent to $S^1\vee S^1$ and, therefore, $S^1$ cannot be a deformation retract of $S^1\vee S^1$ (by the contrapositive, I think).

For solving the problem for all $k$ and all $n$, I tried to compute the higher homotopy groups of both spaces but I don't know how to compute $\pi_n(\bigvee^k S^n)$; I know that the fundamental group of the wedge sum is the free product (with certain conditions) but I don't know if this can be extended to all homotopy groups (but I don't believe that).

How can I show that $S^n$ is not a deformation retract of $\bigvee^k S^n$? give me some hints please.

Comment: If you want a calculation of $\pi_n(\bigvee^k S^n)$ using excision, see example 4.26 in Hatcher's Algebraic Topology. Alternatively, you might want to appeal to Homology instead. The latter method might be easier depending on what you already know.

Comment: this is interesting, I'll see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculation of homotopy groups is difficult. I recommend to use homology groups instead. It is well-known (see for example [Homology of wedge sum is the direct sum of homologies](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/519161)) that
$$H_n(\bigvee^k S^n) \approx \mathbb Z^k$$
which gives you the desired result.

Comment: I didn't think on homology, now I remember that homology groups are isomorphic when there is a homotopy equivalence, That's a good idea, thank you very much.